# Bitbucket - No binary for Chrome browser on your platform

Tags: reactjs, bitbucket, karma-runner, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm working on basic react project and I'm able to run test with karma and mocha on my mac with chrome.
But bitbucket pipeline says that I do not have a chrome, so the question is how to install chrome there and will I have to install it every time with build?

my yml

```
image: node:7.10.0
    pipelines:
      default:
        - step:
            script:
              - npm install -g bower
              - bower install --allow-root
              - npm install
              - npm test
```

karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['mocha'],
    files: [
        './tests/*.js'
    ],
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {
        './tests/*.js': ['webpack']
    },
    // webpack configuration
    webpack: require('./webpack.dev.js'),
    webpackMiddleware: {
        stats: 'errors-only'
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'], //run in Chrome
    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: true,
    concurrency: Infinity
});
```

};

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line `image: node:7.10.0` in your `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file specifies a Docker image to use. In your case, it’s a plain node version 7.10.0 image, so there is no Chrome contained in it.

There are two things you can do:

- Read about Docker, learn how to create your own image that includes Chrome (or whatever other software) and then use that image in your pipeline
- Or, probably far easier: search for an existing Docker image created by someone else which includes node, Chrome and possibly other software you might need. Then, use that image in the `image: <image-name>` configuration line.

In either case, once you have a suitable image, this will be needed when your pipeline is run and Chrome will be available immediately, and you will not need any kind of “installation”.

Comment: As a bonus, if all the tools are already in the image, then you don't need to spend build minutes fetching or installing them.

Comment: I use [circleci node-browsers images](https://hub.docker.com/r/circleci/node/) which contain most usual things needed for testing with Firefox and Chrome.